# Changing background with jQuery getting stuck or can't update img's src attribute

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, google-chrome

I've spent a few hours now trying to figure this one.

I've got a store display that cycles through properties and I've knocked up a simple gallery sort of script. For the last week it has worked beautifully.

I went in today to tinker some unrelated JavaScript (but on the same page) and now there is an issue.

To make the images fade to each other, I update the `img`'s `src`, and then fade it out over the next image of the `img` element's containing element's background.

What seems to happen now is that occasionally the `#main-image`'s background gets stuck on a previous image, despite me setting it with jQuery's `css()` method.

It is available to view here

http://vanquish.websitewelcome.com/~utopia66/store-display

I must stress this is happening in Google Chrome, and I am targeting that browser only.

For your convenience too I have sped up the rate of cycling through images to save you time.

So, why is the image getting stuck and how can I fix it? **update** on closer inspection it may be that the `img` element is getting stuck, i.e. it can not update the `src` attribute. **updating again** actually I'm *pretty sure* it is the background.

JavaScript is here

http://vanquish.websitewelcome.com/~utopia66/assets/js/display.js

I very much appreciate any help!

Thanks a bunch.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm *pretty sure* I solved it by wrapping the `backgroundImage` values with double quotes like this.

```
$('#something').css({ backgroundImage: 'url("' + pathToImage + '")' });
```

Some of the newer images had parenthesis in their filename.

One of the more frustrating ones!

Thanks if anyone looked into it for me :)

Answer (score 0):

What I've found with images and fade-in/out is to do it **after** the image is loaded. This will fix flicker type effect when the image is first loaded after a refresh:

```
$('#something').attr('src', 'pathToImage').load(function(){$(#something).fadeOut('slow')});
```